# Dynamic Column in Select Clause Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using `System.Linq.Dynamic`, Here is my Code :-

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
string para = "Cat";
var paraData = ctx.tblEmployee.Where("id=6").Select("new(" + para + ")");
string value = paraData;
```

In the above Code i didn't get the `value` but i get a sql query string as a result.

How to get the value of the dynamic column?

Comment: Why don't you just execute the query string with something like Dapper?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
string para = "Cat";
var paraData = (IEnumerable<string>)ctx.tblEmployee.Where("id=6").Select(para);
string value = paraData.FirstOrDefault();
```

To work with the result from the dynamic expression you have to cast the result. The result is a List (not really, but the IQueryable- or IEnumerable- Collection even if the result contains only one item.
To get the one Item you have to append First() or better FirstOrDefault() to prevent an exception, if no employee has the id 6.